# Importing columns from another sheet and joining

Tags: google-sheets

I have a master sheet and I would like to import to another sheet all rows but only columns D, I, J, K, L, M, N, P, Q, S, T, U, V, W. But I would also like to join some of these columns. 
I'd like to join the following:

1. D, I & J
2. K, L, M & N
3. P, Q, S, T & U
4. V & W.

I'd also like to have the information continue to feed through as more gets added to the master sheet. Is this actually possible?

Comment: Welcome. Perhaps you could show us what you've tried already, what your source and target sheet look like, maybe even share your spreadsheet.

Comment: And to join columns, you can use an array formula : `=ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!A1:A & Sheet1!B1:B)`